# Neural Neworks SOM tutorial

Tags: neural-network, som

Can anyone recommend me some good tutorial regarding SOM? I googled up some, but I'm not very satisfied with them.

Thanks,
proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for in particular and what language are you using?
One of the easiest explanations of SOM involve the automatic mapping of similar colours as described [here](http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/soms/) and [here](http://ai-depot.com/Tutorial/SomColour.html). I always liked [AI-Junkie's site](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html) which also demonstrates the colour classification. Try and understand why the colours merge as that is probably the 'hello world' equivalent in Self-Organizing Maps.

Is there something in particular you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks fpr links. AI-junkie link was what i was looking for.